# Symfony2, Is there any way to use Monolog to split the log files every day?

Tags: symfony, logging, monolog

I would like to use Monolog in symfony2 application for logging, but my question is how can I split the file every day instead of appending to the same file?

I would like my log file to be somthing like below:

```
"%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.%date%.log"
```

Which %date% should be replaced with real date.

Comment: See [log-rotating-with-monolog-in-symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126530/log-rotating-with-monolog-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what you would normally use [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) for ...

... but you can adjust the builtin [RotatingFileHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php) to achieve your aim.