# Log rotating with Monolog in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I'd like to know if there's any possibility to configure Monolog in Symfony2 to create a new log file every day, for example : 2013-11-21-prod.log.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a logger called `rotating_file`.
Here is a sample configuration:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  rotating_file
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
```

Comment: @Seldaek Maybe you could post an answer illustrating it? As the creator of Monolog you know better than me how to achieve that! ;-)

Comment: As the creator of Monolog I know that I didn't want to rewrite a tool that's been there forever and works very well, but I am no logrotate pro :) Anyway @loicfavory posted a sample logrotate config below so I'll leave it at that. I just wanted to point out that not all tasks are best done with php.

Comment: This would be even better if it had an option to compress old logs too. :)

Answer (score 41):

On Linux, you can use `logrotate` (I don't know if there are similar solutions on Windows or macO)

In `/etc/logrotate.d/` create a file (eg. `sf2_myapp`) and add this content:

```
/path/to/your/symfony_app/app/logs/prod.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 14
        compress
}
```

You should look for "logrotate" on Google for more information

Comment: sharedscripts isn't needed if you're just rotating one file and you're not using any scripts (like a postrotate).

Comment: and if you want for manually force rotation once you made this config file,  run `logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/sf2_myapp`